# Is there anything readily available in the .NET framework of the form EventArgs<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Is there something like this already available in the .NET framework?

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs {
    private readonly T data;

    public EventArgs(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I know there is a generic event handler, I'm kinda surprised I can't find a generic EventArgs class.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why the regular EventArgs even exists.  It adds no functionality to the system (and holds no data and exposes no behavior).  Therefore a "generic equivalent" doesn't really even make sense.

Comment: It does exist in some assemblies/namespaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312134/does-net-have-a-built-in-eventargst/15896769#15896769

Comment: See also this relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/129613/1298001

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Mainly because it fails the tests posed before something it added to the framework

- How useful is it?  (Marginly -- only useful if you only need one data member. As opposed to `EventHandler<>` which is good for event handler regardless of the number of parameters used.)
- How hard is it to write yourself? (not very hard)
- Is it needed in the framework itself?  (No.  Distinct classes are used, so new members could be added in the future if needed.  As opposed to `Func<>` & `Action<>` which are used by the framework.)

(UPDATED based on comments)

Comment: It's certainly as useful as having a EventHandler<T>. Yet, that one exists.

Comment: +1 - I have to agree with this, inheriting and adding the properties you need seems much more useful in most cases.

Comment: You could have something like EventArgs<T>, EventArgs<T, K>, EventArgs<T, K, Z>, etc. It'd certainly ease up things and wouldn't give them any trouble doing so. It's like saying there is really no point in having all those Action<...> and Func<...>.

Comment: @devoured - `Func` is supported in the language's syntax, and is widely useful. `EventArgs<T, K, Z>` will just let you create event arguments with properties **without meaningful names** (like a Tuple) - something that you probably want to avoid.