# EventHandler vs. EventHandler<TEventArgs>

Tags: c#, events, delegates

According to the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668107/6197785) there is no difference, but in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> Typically, you do not have to declare a delegate for an event, because
>   you can use either the `EventHandler` or the `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`
>   delegate. You should declare a delegate only in rare scenarios, such
>   as making your class available to legacy code that cannot use
>   generics.

So it seems to me that Microsoft highly recommend the generic approach over the simplified and less typing one, but I cannot figure out why or what is the difference?

Comment: You misunderstood the question, it was about `EventHandler<EventArgs>`.  Point is that you can use the generic to declare your own `EventHandler<Something>` where Something is your own class derived from EventArgs that has properties you want to pass to the event subscriber.  Which is *not* the same as the non-generic EventHandler, it doesn't allow passing properties.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both the accepted answer and the MSDN documentation you link to state the same thing, to use either EventHandler or EventHandler<"T"> (the less typing one) instead of creating your own custom delegates.

From the accepted answer: "...you should probably prefer the former over the latter because it's clearer and requires less typing."
The former being:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomeEvent;
```

And from MSDN:
For scenarios where the EventHandler and EventHandler<"TEventArgs"> delegates do not work, you can define a delegate.
Defining a delegate is the 'latter' from the accepted answer:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, as soon as `EventHandler<MyEventArgs>` occurs at least twice in your project, you have produced hard-to-maintain copy & paste code:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ItemBeginningEdit;
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ItemCommited;
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ItemEditCancelled;
...
```

In order to keep your code clean, you should abstract the event handler type by defining your own `MyEventHandler` delegate in this case. If you later want to switch from let's say `MyEventArgs` to `MyEventArgs2`, you only have to change it in one single place:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs2 e);
public event MyEventHandler ItemBeginningEdit;                ^
public event MyEventHandler ItemCommited;                     |
public event MyEventHandler ItemEditCancelled;                |
...
```

Comment: This is only a problem, if you frequently need to update the delegate. I find it in my case, the most common situation is to update the `MyEventArgs` class instead.